# JSON Decode in PHP fails using CURL

Tags: php, json, curl

```
$ch = curl_init('http://www.somesite.com/project/User?id=1&&user=MYUSER');   
$result = curl_exec($ch);   
print $result;   
curl_close($ch);   
$json=json_decode($result,true);

print "-->".$json;   

print "------>".$json['PASSWORD'];`
```

The output I get is:

```
-->1   
------>
```

What is the "1" that is appended towards the end? How do i solve it?

Comment: try `print_r` instead of `print` for your `$json` array

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`$result = curl_exec($ch);` => `$result = true`, you forgot:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
```

Answer (score 1):

My guess is you're using curl incorrectly. You should set **CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER** option to **true**:

```
$ch = curl_init('http://www.somesite.com/project/User?id=1&&user=MYUSER');
curl_setopt( CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
$result = curl_exec($ch);   
print $result;   
curl_close($ch);   
$json=json_decode($result,true);
```

Otherwise you're just printing everything into stdout.